# Network Connection Lost

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am facing to

> Error - The network connection was lost.
>   [image]

I am using `RealmSwift` and `Alamofire` in my project.

This is a real estate app and when ever I am searching properties suddenly I am facing to this error without any exception or error and if I searching again than it works properly.

I don't understand why I am facing this issue.

I am using following code for `JSON` encoding:

```
        Alamofire
            .request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: header)
            .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Are you encoding the parameters as JSON in the request body? If so, encode them as URL:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, myURLString, parameters: parameters, encoding: .URL, headers: myHeaders)
```

Comment: `   Alamofire
    .request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: header)
    .responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
`

Comment: I am using above code can you please explain me that what i need to change in my code.

Comment: I see nothing wrong in your code. What are you sending as encoding variable?

Comment: i am sending *JSONEncoding.default* as encoding variable